# Batik SVG - how to rotate SVG image

Tags: java, svg, rotation, batik

I'm trying to rotate the SVG image using Batik. I have a SVG file that I'm opening like this:

```
InputStream is =  this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("svg/"+name+".svg");

String parser = XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName();
SAXSVGDocumentFactory f = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(parser);

SVGDocument doc = (SVGDocument) f.createDocument("svg/"+name+".svg",is);
```

Then I'm trying to rotate it f.ex. 90 degrees (that is not important). Is there any other way to achieve this than packing the content to a group ( tag) and apply transform attribute to the group?
I was trying to do it using SVGGraphics2D class, but I'm not sure if it is possible and if it is, how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try rotating it by loading it with an SVG fragment identifier i.e. pass something like this file.svg#transform(rotate(180)) to getResourceAsStream.